# Specify an option one or more times in docopt

Tags: docopt

I have a program (in python but that shouldn't matter) that takes some options one or more times, such as:

```
# Valid cases:
python test.py --o 1 --p a <file>
python test.py --o 1 --o 2 --p a --p b <file>
# Invalid:
python test.py --o a <file>
python test.py --p a <file>
python test.py <file>
```

This script works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

"""Test

Usage:
  test.py --o=<arg> [--o=<arg>...] --p=<arg> [--p=<arg>...] <file>

"""
from docopt import docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='Test 1.0')
    print(arguments)
```

However the option is repeated and it feels pretty ugly.  I tried the following:

```
test.py --o=<arg>[...] --p=<arg>[...] <file>
test.py (--o=<arg>)[...] (--p=<arg>)[...] <file>
test.py (--o=<arg>[...]) (--p=<arg>[...]) <file>
```

But none of them worked. The alternative would be to make the option fully optionnal and check its value in the program:

```
  test.py [--o=<arg>...] [--p=<arg>...] <file>
  ...
  if len(arguments["--o"]) < 1:
    raise ValueError("One or more --o required")
  if len(arguments["--p"]) < 1:
    raise ValueError("One or more --p required")
```

But I feel there should be an easy solution to do that with docopt directly. Is there a beautiful way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but

```
Usage:
  test.py (--o=<arg>)... (--p=<arg>)... <file>
```

does what you want.

```
Usage:
  test.py (--o=<arg>...) (--p=<arg>...) <file>
```

Work too.

Comment: @Calimo Good to know :)